# Get document based on last item in arrays property

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I need to retrieve orders, based on the status code on a property on the last element in an array.

My structure is as follows.

```
{
  "_id" : "3580bdba-4017-40af-939d-7391d70b3511",

  "IsPublic" : true,

  "MailReceiptDispatch" : {
    "TransferSupervisor" : {
      "TransferStatuses" : [{
          "TransferState" : 0,
          "TransferTime" : ISODate("2015-05-29T11:21:20.722Z")
        }, {
          "TransferState" : 1,
          "TransferTime" : ISODate("2015-05-29T11:54:10.013Z")
        }, {
          "TransferState" : 2,
          "TransferTime" : ISODate("2015-05-29T11:54:12.462Z")
        }],
      "IsTransferedLimitReached" : false,
      "LatestTransferingStatus" : {
        "TransferState" : 2,
        "TransferTime" : ISODate("2015-05-29T11:54:12.462Z")
      }
    },
    "ExceptionLog" : [],
    "HasWarningBeenSent" : false
  }
}
```

So I need to get the objects I need based on something like: 
{MailReceiptDispatch.TranferSupervisor.TransferStatuses.[Get last in array].TransferState : 2}`

I tried `slice`, but then I just retrieve the object. mI need to look at the objects property. `ElemMatch` does something that might be useful, but I can't figure out how to connect both slice and ElemMatch.

Comment: Could you post some example record in JSON format?

Comment: The post here is about something very similar, you might want to look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294273/mongodb-query-a-json-object-nested-in-an-array I think it can be solved in an elegant via with the aggregation framework (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)

Comment: @Matthias i added the data in JSON format instead.

Comment: @NiclasSchumacher you want to find out only `TransferState:2` right?

Comment: Find any order with TransferState:2 as the last element of the TransferStatuses array I think is what he is asking for.

Comment: @yogesh, You are almost right, but as Matthias says, i want to find the last one, to check what state that is. Because the last state represent the state which the documents MailReceipt is in.
Hopefully it makes sense for you :)

Comment: @NiclasSchumacher so basically you want to find out latest `TransferTime`   `TransferState` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo [Aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) used to find out last `TransferState`, first you [unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) `TransferStatuses` array and used either `sort` or `max` in aggregation to get latest `TransferState` as below :

1> Sort all `TransferTime` in aggregation :

```
 db.collectionName.aggregate({"$unwind":"$MailReceiptDispatch.TransferSupervisor.TransferStatuses"},
                             {"$sort":{"MailReceiptDispatch.TransferSupervisor.TransferStatuses.TransferTime":-1}},
                             {"$group":{"_id":"$_id","TransferState":{"$first":"$MailReceiptDispatch.TransferSupervisor.TransferStatuses.TransferState"},
                                         "TransferTime":{"$first":"$MailReceiptDispatch.TransferSupervisor.TransferStatuses.TransferTime"}}}
                             ).pretty()
```

2> Use `max` in aggregation as :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({"$unwind":"$MailReceiptDispatch.TransferSupervisor.TransferStatuses"},
                            {"$group":{"_id":"$_id","TransferState":{"$max":"$MailReceiptDispatch.TransferSupervisor.TransferStatuses.TransferState"},
                                       "TransferTime":{"$max":"$MailReceiptDispatch.TransferSupervisor.TransferStatuses.TransferTime"}}}
                           ).pretty()
```

Comment: seems good, how would i check if the TransferState == 2 ? in those cases you listed. 
And thank you very much for your time!

Comment: should write `$match` after unwind like this `{$match:{MailReceiptDispatch.TransferSupervisor.TransferStatuses.TransferState:2}}`