# How do I efficiently access JSON documents from an array of JSON documents, by using value of embedded document?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, performance

I need a method/strategy in JavaScript to access documents from a JSON array. I need something that works kind of like $elemMatch in MongoDB Shell.

The data is in the following format:

```
[
    { 
      a : '1',
      b : '2',
      c : '3'
    },
    { 
      a : '4',
      b : '5',
      c : '6'
    },
    {...},
    {...}
]
```

So all the documents have the same keys and I need to access the 'c' value when I have the 'a' value.

Is any way to do this efficiently in JavaScript, i.e. without having to loop through the entire array? This will form part of a much larger query function and performance is extremely important.

Comment: what means "*access the 'c' value when I have the 'a' value*"?

Comment: I have the value of 'a' (from previous steps) and I need to find the corresponding value for 'c'. So for example, if I have a = 4, I need to query the array, to return c = 6 to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the find command with nested data. Check [this link](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html) for javascript syntax and the accepted answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294273/mongodb-query-a-json-object-nested-in-an-array) for a general idea on what you're trying to do.

Edit: For javascript, you could try to use the match command with the aggregation pipeline framework ([more info here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match)).

Comment: My apologies, I see now that my question was not very clear. I am looking for a way to do this in JavaScript not in MongoDB. I will edit the question now.

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for, or I am misunderstanding you. I have already queried the database, and received a very large multi-tier document. Now, embedded within the document, I have this array, and I need to retrieve a specific field from it, based on another field in the document. So, the document is already in memory in a JavaScript function at this stage.

Comment: Okay wait, I think I understand what you mean. Are you suggesting I modify my query in order to use the aggregation framework, to filter the document received? Is that possible though? Since, the array is deep within the main document and I require the rest of the data, how would I then only extract the one document from the array?

Comment: Looking at it again, I don't think my problem can be solved by the $match stage. Since I already have a query that is perfectly indexed and returns the correct document. My problem lies with efficiently extracting the correct data from the retrieved document.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now... So what other data do you need from the main document? Can't you modify your query to get all the data you need and then filter by using the aggregation thing? Once you are querying for that data, why do you need more fields?

Comment: You were asking about something similar to $elemMatch in mongodb, that's why I suggested the $match method in the aggregation pipeline. They are supposed to be equivalent :/

Comment: What I meant by that is, a method that efficiently matches on elements of an array based on certain field (may be a slightly inaccurate comparison, my apologies). I will investigate rewriting the query to only get the required fields, but the deeply embedded nature of the document makes it complicated, and also I have to work with predefined indexes, and cannot afford non-index scans.